Flutter Google map gestures not working inside modal bottom sheet
I'm implementing a bottom sheet in my Flutter app to select a location using Google Maps. While the map displays correctly, gestures like pinch-to-zoom and scroll (pan) do not work when interacting with the map inside the bottom sheet.
I suspect it might be related to gesture recognizers or the interaction between the bottom sheet and the map widget.
Here is my showLocationSelection method:
void showLocationSelection(
  BuildContext context,
  ThemeData theme,
  CommonColorsExt? commonColors,
  MerchantQuestionsViewModel viewModel,
) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
        top: Radius.circular(16.0),
      ),
    ),
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); // Dismiss keyboard
        },
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(6.91177, 79.85043),
                    zoom: 15.0,
                  ),
                  onTap: (LatLng position) {
                    viewModel.setGeoLocation(position);
                  },
                  markers: viewModel.markers,
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
                    Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => ScaleGestureRecognizer(),
                    ),
                  },
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  myLocationEnabled: false,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}



I have implemented a Google Map inside a modal bottom sheet in Flutter, and I want to allow pinch-to-zoom, scrolling, and other map gestures to function properly within the bottom sheet. I have enabled zoomGesturesEnabled and scrollGesturesEnabled properties in the GoogleMap widget, but the pinch-to-zoom and scrolling gestures do not seem to be working when the map is displayed inside the bottom sheet.
I expect that when I open the bottom sheet with the Google Map, I should be able to zoom in/out and scroll the map as I would in a normal view. However, these gestures are not responding as expected.
I also attempted adjusting the gestureRecognizers and other related settings but did not achieve the desired functionality.

You are right on your assumption, the bottom sheet is capturing the gestures and does not allow the map to take over them.
Did you try to use a GestureDetector to resolve it? Something like this:
void showLocationSelection(
  BuildContext context,
  ThemeData theme,
  CommonColorsExt? commonColors,
  MerchantQuestionsViewModel viewModel,
) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
        top: Radius.circular(16.0),
      ),
    ),
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); // Dismiss keyboard
        },
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onVerticalDragUpdate: (_) {}, // Prevents bottom sheet gestures
                  child: GoogleMap(
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(6.91177, 79.85043),
                      zoom: 15.0,
                    ),
                    onTap: (LatLng position) {
                      viewModel.setGeoLocation(position);
                    },
                    markers: viewModel.markers,
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
                      Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(
                        () => ScaleGestureRecognizer(),
                      ),
                      Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(
                        () => PanGestureRecognizer(),
                      ),
                      Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(
                        () => TapGestureRecognizer(),
                      ),
                    },
                    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                    scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                    myLocationEnabled: false,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}


Thanks for the response. But it didn't work.
